# List to JSON : Play Framework : Java

Tags: java, angularjs, json, playframework

I am using play framework with Java.How can we convert List to Json ?

I have tried with following code :

```
List<XYZ> data = PQRDao.func01();

return ok(Json.toJson(data));
```

Output :

```
[["1","APPLE"],["2","BANANA"],["3',"ORANGE"]]
```

Actual requirement :

```
[{"code": "1","fruitName": "APPLE"},{"code": "2","fruitName": "BANANA"},{"code":  "3',"fruitName": "ORANGE"}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[["1","APPLE"],["2","BANANA"],["3',"ORANGE"]]` is this the list you actually have ? Actually its list of lists not a single list with objects

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple for loop you need.below is the working code

```html
<script>
  
  var list = [["1","APPLE"],["2","BANANA"],["3","ORANGE"]];
  var finalList =[];

  function createJson () {
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    var item = list[i];
    var obj = {};
    obj.code = item[0];
    obj.fruitName =item[1];
    finalList.push(obj);
}
   console.log(finalList);
  }
  </script>
<button onclick="createJson()"> Format</button>
```

Comment: I have tried with following code but getting run time error " [CompletionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to models.XYZ":  List<XYZ> data = PQRDao.func01();
 
    
 ArrayNode result = Json.newArray();
    
 for (XYZ P: data){
  ObjectNode node = Json.newObject();
  node.put("code", p.fruitCode);
  node.put("fruitName", p.fruitName);
  result.add(node);
   }

 return ok(result);

Comment: List<XYZ> data = PQRDao.func01();
 
    
 ArrayNode result = Json.newArray();
    
 for (XYZ P: data){
  ObjectNode node = Json.newObject();
  node.put("code", p.fruitCode);
  node.put("fruitName", p.fruitName);
  result.add(node);
   }

 return ok(result);

Comment: ERROR :   "[CompletionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to models.XYZ]

Comment: are you trying yo do this in Java ? or JS ?

Comment: I trying to do this in Java in play framework. In front end I am using agnular js and calling REST service which return json object.

Comment: Try doing it in js after u get hain output not sure how ur class looks like as u are getting class cast exception